# Std::vectors - copying vs creating a reference

Tags: c++, stdvector

I'm a little bit new to C++ and coming mostly from Python I am confused about this statement:

```
std::vector<int> b = a;
```

will this create `b` as a copy (new object with same contents) of vector `a` or as a reference to it? I.e. if a subsequent change is made to `b`, e.g.

```
b.append(1);
```

will that change be reflected in `a` as well (as it would if `a` and `b` reference the same object)?

Comment: You could have the answer easily by testing the code.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, assignment in C++ almost always creates copies, unless references or pointers are involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> std::vector<int> b = a;
> ```
>
> will this creates b as a copy (new object with same contents) of vector a or as a reference to it?

that create *b* as a new *vector* being a copy, so `b.append(1);` does not change *a*